# Call form load event in another function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I need advice on how to call the form load at other areas in my code to avoid excess copy and paste. I basically need to load the page at other areas after pressing buttons in an interface. I need all of the code that exists and as you can see it is quite a bit to copy and paste multiple times.

```
public void FBinterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSerial.Focus();

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string SerialQuery = "select SerialNumber from Inventory";
        command.CommandText = SerialQuery;

        //TO READ DATA
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboSerial.Items.Add(reader["SerialNumber"]);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        connection.Close();
    }
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string PartQuery = "select PartNumber from Inventory";
        command.CommandText = PartQuery;

        //TO READ DATA
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboPart.Items.Add(reader["PartNumber"]);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        connection.Close();
    }
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string ROnumberQuery = "select ROnumber from Inventory";
        command.CommandText = ROnumberQuery;

        //TO READ DATA
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboRO.Items.Add(reader["ROnumber"]);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        connection.Close();
    }
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string LocationQuery = "select Location from Inventory";

        command.CommandText = LocationQuery;

        //TO READ DATA
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            comboLocation.Items.Add(reader["Location"]);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call the event handler. Put the necessary code into a separate function, and then call that whenever you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your logic to another method and call it when you want

```
public void FBinterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyLogic();
}

private void MyLogic()
{
    txtSerial.Focus();
    try
    {
          //removed for brevity 
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

now call `MyLogic` method when you want.

For example:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //some code

     MyLogic(); //calling the whole logic you want.

     //extra code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
FBinterface_Load(this,null);
```

Comment: If you *were* going to do this, you should pass `EventArgs.Empty` as the second parameter, rather than `null`. But this is bad form, event handlers should only be called in response to their associated events. A better solution would be to extract the relevant code into a separate method.

Comment: That is definitely what I want to do but.....I'm not sure how I start it, for example: "public void FBinterface_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)", just the way that starts.

Comment: Just use the this call as it is from any function.

Comment: Well what I mean is do I start it like this: "public void ItemsLoad()" ? or am I missing parameters for this to be valid ?

Comment: If you are asking how to call the `FBinterface_Load` function, then just use the code in my post. `public void ...` is not used in the function call.